# can not restart apache2

Tags: openssl

any input?

```
root@prome-mdt-dhcp412:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                           [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: symbol PEM_read_bio_ECPKParameters, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: root@prome-mdt-dhcp412:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ldd /usr/bin/openssl

 
 libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/staf/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f8df5add000)
 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/staf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f8df5721000)

Comment: How did you install apache?

Comment: Why are you using root account? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have such essential system libraries in `/usr/local/`. 
Remove them and consider to reinstall them from their package:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/staf/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo rm /usr/local/staf/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl1.0.0
```